# In contenteditable, I lose listener after a move of a selection

Tags: javascript, listener, contenteditable

In a contenteditable div,
when I select a sentence with inside a element with listeners and I move the sentence elsewhere, I lose these listeners.

Do you know why ?

https://jsfiddle.net/er069bsj/

```html
<div contenteditable=true>
If you move by selection this sentence "LOREM <span id="1" class="element"  onmouseover="console.log('mouseover word 1');this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'" onmouseout="console.log('mouseout word 1');this.style.backgroundColor='red'">WORD 1</span>FINIBUS", you lose the listener.<br> Other example with this sentence "NNULLAM <span id="2" class="element" onmouseout="console.log('mouseout word 2');this.style.backgroundColor='red'">WORD 2</span>METUS".
```

You can for example move the sentence LOREM WORD 1 FINIBUS in my Fiddle example and you can see mouseover and mouseout don't work after the move.

Comment: I would imagine the browser is "re-building" the content of the editable area and the "moved" `span`, is actually an entirely new and independent element. But that is entirely speculation.

Comment: Yes, I think so.
I found a solution I think.
I use a function to add listeners and I call this function on the dragend